# G-Wan and default hello handler?

Tags: handlers, g-wan

I'm trying out the handlers shipped with g-wan but i cant seem to locate any good documentation on this subject.

I have renamed the main_hello.c__ to main_hello.c and restarted g-wan.

But how do i se the result of the handler?

It seems nothing is triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I renamed the main_hello.c__ to main_hello.c

Handler names are following conventions that you should use. Read the G-WAN PDF manual, and the [Developers' Web site page](http://gwan.com/developers#handler) which presents the different kinds of handlers, and how to use them.

In short, `Connection handlers` are defined per-host and must be named `main.c`.

And `Content-type handlers` are defined per-MIME type (HTML, GIF, FLV, etc.) and must be named `html.c`, `gif.c`, `flv.c`, etc.

A handler named `main_hello.c` will just be ignored because it targets no defined use.

> how do i se the result of the handler?

In the source code of some G-WAN handler examples you will see commented `printf()` or `puts()` calls that let you know during development when a handler state is executed.

Since the *"result of a handler"* is dependent on what the handler does so there is no way to see what it does unless it has a visible interaction with the server's behavior (filtering, logging, rewriting, etc.).